# WPF - TextBox won't respond to PropertyChanged in multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

I have a textbox that should show hex value of a color. App can be in two states:

1) In edit mode (IsEdit==true) textbox binds to my model property and

2) when is not in edit mode (IsEdit==false) textbox binds to slider 
representing RGB colors. Changing each color value with slider, hex value in textbox also changes and vice versa. Textbox is also binded to my model property so that I could save changes later.

**Problem**: When app is in edit mode changing textbox text property manually triggers converter and sends text value to model and sliders but when I change sliders, textbox text is changing but it doesn’t send data to model. Why?! I’ve tried everything I could think of. Changing binding mode, notifyontargetupdated… It should work… Can someone please explain.

I tried to simplify so if I missed anything important please let me know.

XAML code:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="120" Height="120" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Fill="{Binding ElementName=tbxHexColor, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource HexToColorConverter}}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbxHexColor" CharacterCasing="Upper">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SlidersToHexConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding ElementName="sliderRed" Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="sliderGreen" Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="sliderBlue" Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding Path="RGBHelper"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
<Slider x:Name="sliderRed" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,5,0,3" Maximum="255">
    <Slider.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=red, FallbackValue=0}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=red, Mode=OneTime}"/> 
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Slider.Style>
</Slider>
<Slider x:Name="sliderGreen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,3" Maximum="255">
    <Slider.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=green, FallbackValue=0}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=green, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Slider.Style>
</Slider>
<Slider x:Name="sliderBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,3" Maximum="255">
    <Slider.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=blue, FallbackValue=0}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEdit}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding SelectedColor.RGBHex, Converter={StaticResource HexToRGBConverter}, ConverterParameter=blue, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Slider.Style>
</Slider>
```

Converters:

```
public class HexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {    
        string input = "#" + value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input == "#" || input.Length < 7)
        {
            input = "#00FFFFFF";
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(input));            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



public class SlidersToHexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string hex = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int itemInt = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[i]);
            if (itemInt != 0)
            {
                string a = itemInt.ToString("X");
                if (a.Length == 1)
                {
                    hex += "0" + a;
                }
                else
                {
                    hex += a;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hex += "00";
            }
        }

        return hex;                                   
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] sliderValues = new object[4] { 0, 0, 0, "" };

        if (value.ToString().Length == 6)
        {
            string r = value.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
            string g = value.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
            string b = value.ToString().Substring(4, 2);

            double rr = int.Parse(r, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            double gg = int.Parse(g, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            double bb = int.Parse(b, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            sliderValues[0] = (object)rr;
            sliderValues[1] = (object)gg;
            sliderValues[2] = (object)bb;
        }

        sliderValues[3] = value.ToString();

        return sliderValues;
    }
}



public class HexToRGBConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        string hex = value.ToString();
        string colorHex = "0";
        switch (parameter.ToString())
        {
            case "red":
                colorHex = hex.Substring(0, 2);
                break;
            case "green":
                colorHex = hex.Substring(2, 2);
                break;
            case "blue":
                colorHex = hex.Substring(4, 2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return int.Parse(colorHex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Tried everything in MultiBinding part of XAML. Changing: NotifyOnSourceUpdated, NotifyOnTargetUpdated, Mode, UpdateSourceTrigger... Nothing works.